# How to install cpupower on Ubuntu 14.04 (kernel 4.6.0)

Tags: ubuntu

I've tried to use the `cpupower` command on my Ubuntu machine and got this error message

```
WARNING: cpupower not found for kernel 4.6.0

  You may need to install the following packages for this specific kernel:
    linux-tools-4.6.0-4.6.0
    linux-cloud-tools-4.6.0-4.6.0
```

I've tried to install `linux-tools` for kernel 4.6.0 using `apt-get` but it seems that it only supports version up to 4.4.0-59.

Is there any way to run cpupower on my Ubuntu machine properly?

Comment: How did you install your 4.6 kernel?

Comment: I just downloaded the ubuntu 14.04 from the legitimate repo.

Comment: Not very helpful, but cpupower works for me in 16.10 (kernel 4.8*)

Comment: Hmm.. Did you get the cpupower with the apt-get command? or is it pre-installed when you install the ubuntu?

Comment: It's provided by the package `linux-tools-common` which was in the installation, not installed later by me through APT

Answer (score 8):

this must work with any version:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -y linux-tools-$(uname -r)
```

Answer (score 1):

For **MX Linux** its:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-cpupower
```

Also in MX linux, you can open the **MX Package Installer** and search for 'cpupower' under the Full App Catalog

For **Zorin 15.2** its:

```
sudo apt-get install -y linux-tools-common linux-tools-$(uname -r)
```

You can also go to **Synaptic** and search for linux-tools-common.  You can also search for linux-tools- and the output of uname-r.  ex. linux-tools-5.3.0-42-generic

Answer (score 0):

Some years later...

I had the same problem with `cpupower` in Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS.

I tried installing  `linux-tools-common`, `linux-tools-generic`, and `linux-tools-oem` to no avail. I always got the message

```
cpupower not found for kernel 5.14.0-1033
```

I needed linux-tools specifically for **this** kernel. Sadly, in the `synaptic package manager` there was no trace of such kernel. And even the command `sudo apt-get install -y linux-tools-$(uname -r)` gave me the message

```
Unable to locate package linux-tools-5.14.0-1033-oem
```

**Solution:**

1. Download the `.deb` package at the [official site for Ubuntu Package Search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/) searching for `linux-tools-5.14.0-1033-oem`
2. Install the package easily on command line with `sudo dpkg -i mypackage.deb` (watch out that you have already all dependencies installed ;))

In my case I had to install two packages: first, the dependency `linux-oem-5.14-tools-5.14.0-1033_5.14.0-1033.36_amd64.deb` and, then, the main package `linux-tools-5.14.0-1033-oem_5.14.0-1033.36_amd64.deb`