# Keep the PC in low power, but not sleeping

Tags: ubuntu, power-management

I am trying to use my old notebook to monitor some things, and I really don't need it to run past its lowest frequency, since it will only gather data every few minutes or so and relay it. But the problem is, I don't want it to sleep either.

I am using `pm-powersave true` but after installing it, suddenly the PC sleeps very often and the ping only replied a few seconds after I press the button at the notebook. I've tried with cable and wifi.

The OS is Ubuntu Server 23.04, running on an old Compaq Presario with Core Duo processor.

Is there a way to prevent this?

What is the correct way to keep it at minimum frequency but stays awake?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't want the laptop went to sleep or if you closed the lid, you can try the following:

1. Edit and uncomment this lines in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`

   ```
   HandleLidSwitch=ignore
   HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=ignore
   HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore
   ```
2. Install and run `cpufrequtils`

   `apt install cpufrequtils`

   Set the CPU governor to `powersave`

   `cpufreq-set -r -g powersave`

   - [How to use cpufrequtils](https://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_use_cpufrequtils)
   - [cpufreq-info(1)](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/cpufrequtils/cpufreq-info.1.en.html)
3. Disable suspend with `systemctl`

   - [How do I disable my system from going to sleep?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47311/how-do-i-disable-my-system-from-going-to-sleep)
4. Use `cpupower` from the `linux-tools-generic`

   ```
   apt install linux-tools-generic
   cpupower frequency-set -g powersave
   cpupower frequency-set -d <min_frequency>
   ```

   - [cpupower - Shows and sets processor power related values](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/cpupower.1.html)
   - [How to install cpupower on Ubuntu 20.04 with kernel 5.17+](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1415288/how-to-install-cpupower-on-ubuntu-20-04-with-kernel-5-17)
   - [How to install cpupower on Ubuntu 14.04 (kernel 4.6.0)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/341927/how-to-install-cpupower-on-ubuntu-14-04-kernel-4-6-0)

*Do a reboot after you change it.*

More Sources:

- [Ubuntu 22.04 is sleeping even though I changed the power settings so it shouldn't sleep](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/714803/ubuntu-22-04-is-sleeping-even-though-i-changed-the-power-settings-so-it-shouldn)
- [How To: Disable Sleep And Hibernation on Ubuntu Server](https://linux-tips.us/how-to-disable-sleep-and-hibernation-on-ubuntu-server/)
- [How to Prevent Ubuntu from Going into Sleep Mode](https://itsfoss.com/ubuntu-prevent-sleep/)
- [Disable Suspend and Hibernation Modes In Linux](https://blog.wijman.net/disable-suspend-and-hibernation-modes-in-linux/)

Comment: Are these 4 separate alternatives for solving the problem or you need to do all of them?
Could you please clarify? Thanks.

Comment: @arielf they are to perform different task I guess. I had added settings to `logind.conf` before asking, and that let me close the lid and keep the notebook running, tucked neatly at the gap between the machines. The second one, `cpufrequtils` is to set the power management to stay low power. The third one is keeping my notebook from being suspended, that was modified when I installed `pm-powersave` I think. And the fourth one is to keep it low, kind like my `pm-powersave true`, but without extra bells and whistles. So I removed `pm-powersave`. Anyway, now it is running cool, and stays online.

Comment: It sounds like these are independent ways to achieve the goal which are not exactly equivalent or identical. In addition it sounds like you don't necessarily need all the 4 suggested actions to achieve the OP goal. To make this clearer in the answer, I would change "the following" into "one or more of the following independent alternatives". Cheers.