Suspend issues: laptop lid close wakes up system from suspension (s2idle)
I am currently struggling with an issue on a new Lenovo IdeaPad 9 (AMD) laptop (16AHP9)
Problem is that when I suspend the system and then I close the lid, the system wakes up immediately. If I keep the lid open I don't observe any issues and the system keeps sleeping.
Some additional information:

I'm running PopOs 22.04
this CPU (AMD Ryzen 7 8845HS) supports only s2idle sleep (no deep), so this is the one it's used currently
solutions I already tried and did not work:

add a new custom rule in /etc/udev/rules.d/20-suspend-fixes.rules with multiple entries like ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="acpi", DRIVERS=="button", ATTRS{hid}=="PNP0C0C", ATTR{power/wakeup}="disabled" pointing to all devices that seem related to LID switches
change all *Lid* configurations in /etc/systemd/logind.conf to ignore lid actions
modify /etc/UPower/UPower.conf and set IgnoreLid=true
create a service that disables all devices in cat /proc/acpi/wakeup (makes sense it did not work, as these have S-state S3/S4



I already wasted too much time on this issue, but in the end what I want is that closing the laptop lid does nothing at all.
Is there something else I can try to disable completely the switch before I go completely crazy and disassemble the laptop hinge to unsolder the physical switch?

Check this https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/751947

Blacklisting ideapad_laptop module

@Z0OM thanks for the suggestion, I tried to blacklist the module using sudo kernelstub -d "modprobe.blacklist=ideapad_laptop" and rebooting, but no change in the suspension behavior unfortunately

As soon as your system does the problem wakeup, sudo journalctl  --since="-5 minutes" will show you system logs covering the suspend/wakeupj events.
